# pass jquery css from json database

Tags: jquery, css, json

I'm trying to pass css attribute into jquery method and these css attributes are stored in json database. It doesn't seem to be working though, I think that simply inserting path to json variable isn't the right way to do that.

Here is my json variable line:

```
{
"galleryeleven":"", 
"galleryelevenlink":"", 
"galleryelevendisplay":"none !important"
}
```

and here is jquery line I'm trying to insert it into:

```
$('#galleryeleven').attr('src',database[globalswitchNumber].galleryeleven);
$('#galleryelevenlink').attr('href',database[globalswitchNumber].galleryelevenlink);
$('#galleryeleven').css("display",database[globalswitchNumber].galleryelevendisplay);
```

So jquery .attr methods work great, but .css doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `!important` property and it will work. I don't know why though.

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8d8pd0r/)

Do you really need `!important`  ?  `.css()` modifies the style attribute in the DOM so it will be over other css rules at stylesheets.